# Laravel 5.6 htmlspecialchars when using {{ }}

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I have recently upgraded a project from Laravel 5.5 to 5.6 and I have some encoded characters like ' that were not there before. If I downgrade again to Laravel 5.5 leaving everything the same (just downgrade a couple of packages to make them compatible) the characters are displayed as expected.

I have checked the documentation and it mention the same in 5.5 and 5.6 about {{ }} and {!! !!}: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#displaying-data

The database connection is, and was before the upgrade, set to use utf8mb4 as charset and utf8mb4_unicode_ci as collation.

Any idea why this is happening in Laravel 5.6? One (quick) solution will be to replace the {{ }} with {!! !!} or {{ html_entity_decode($text, ENT_QUOTES) }} but I feel that something more general could be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the upgrade guide here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade

The answer to your question is in `Blade > HTML Entity Encoding`.

In your `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`,  add this code `Blade::withoutDoubleEncoding();` in the boot function. Here's the whole file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Blade::withoutDoubleEncoding();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this has fixed most of the cases